# Sharing Framebuffers Across Threads

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have a video app that does both a live preview as well as a still image capture while the preview is running. I am using 4 textures that are pre-generated when the app loads. I am accessing the textures across three threads.

In order to make the live preview work, I had to make a Sharegroup (see below) so that the `captureOutput` method could store a result in a framebuffer called `FBO_OUT`. Then, in order to display to the screen I needed to access `FBO_OUT` for the call to `presentRenderbuffer`. If I didn't use the Sharegroup, I just got a bunch of gibberish.

```
CAEAGLLayer* eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
eaglLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking,
                                kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat,
                                nil];
oglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
offscreenContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:[oglContext API] sharegroup:oglContext.sharegroup];
if (!oglContext || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:oglContext]) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with OpenGL context.");
    [self release];

    return nil;
}
```

Periodically, inside the `captureOutput` I need to call this code:

```
#define SHAREGROUP_CONTEXT [[[appDelegate mainViewController] oglView] offscreenContext]

 if ([EAGLContext currentContext] != SHAREGROUP_CONTEXT) {
     NSLog(@"setting context");
     glFlush();
     [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:SHAREGROUP_CONTEXT];
 }

 @synchronized(SHAREGROUP_CONTEXT)
 {
    /* process pixels */
 }

 glFlush();  // at end of method
```

This works fine, the problem, is that I'm now trying to do the same thing after taking a Still Image (while the preview is still running) via `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` block, however I am getting gibberish again even though I've tried doing this:

```
AVCaptureConnection *sic = [AVCamUtilities connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[[self stillImageOutput] connections]];

[[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:sic
                                                     completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) 
 {

     @synchronized(SHAREGROUP_CONTEXT)
     {

         /* generate new textures to process the imageDataSampleBuffer and cry */
     }
```

This seems to be a problem with contexts and threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. You need to make sure the `@synchronized` block is in *both* methods. This took me so long to find because something very strange was happening with my shaders. One of the filenames was lowercase on disk when XCode thought they were all uppercase. This made the shader work in the live preview but gave me a white screen in the still image capture portion. No idea why.

Comment: You might be sacrificing a bit of performance by using `@synchronized` to lock your accesses here: http://perpendiculo.us/?p=133 .  An NSLock has much less overhead, with a pthread mutex being even cheaper.  I've seen locking consume a lot of performance in my OpenGL applications in the past, so this might add up.  Also, you could contemplate using a single-wide dispatch queue and dispatch all actions that access a single resource (like a context) to that queue.  This is a lock-free way of guaranteeing safe access to this shared resource, and has been my preferred approach recently.